# Trigonometry equivalent

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, noneuclidean-geometry

> $\sin (A) = \sin 3x$ is equivalent to $\sin(A) = 3 \sin(x) - 4\sin^3(x)$, then $-\cos 3x$ is $-4\cos^3x + 3\cos$.

is that correct? I just want to make sure I'm distributing the negative sign correctly.

Comment: Yup ur answer is right

Comment: @SakethMalyala thank you!